# Remove a field in array in mongodb using codeigniter library

Tags: mongodb, codeigniter

using mongo db library [link](http://intekhab.in/mongodb-library-for-codeigniter.html) for ci  my user collection is as follows

```
{

  "_id" : ObjectId("5a9cf393be713df40e00002d"),
 "id" : "1",
 "name" : "ali",
 "category" :  {
  "back" : "12",
  "front" : "2"
  }

}
```

Delete front : 2 field from my collection i write this code in ci

```
$where = array('_id'=> new MongoId($id));
  $data = array(
    'category' => array(
        'front' => ''
    )
);
  $update = array('$unset' =>  $data);


 $this->mongoci->db->user->update($where,$update);
```

after execute this query the result will be like this

```
{

"_id" : ObjectId("5a9cf393be713df40e00002d"),  
"category" : {    
 "front" : "2"
 }
}
```

i want this result

```
{

 "_id" : ObjectId("5a9cf393be713df40e00002d"),
 "id" : "1",
 "name" : "ali",
 "category" : {
"back" : "12"

 }
}
```

Comment: It's not an array. You can use dot notation to remove field from embedded document. Try `$data = array(     'category.front' => ''  );`

Comment: it works  but it delete the complete category.

Comment: category not show @Veeram

Comment: Is the category an array ? Can you update the post ? What is your mongo server version ?

Comment: 3.0.5 yes category is array

Comment: Try `$where = array('_id'=> new MongoId($id), 'category.front' => '2');   $data = array(     'category.$.front' => ''     )`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166233/discussion-between-unknow-and-veeram).

Comment: its not working [link](https://ibb.co/eqWxsn) view of my collection

Comment: @Veeram this line works for me $data = array( 'category.front' => '' );